# How to use subfolders of the VC++ Include Directories in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, properties, visual-studio-2017, include, header-files

I have a given solution, not written by me, from Visual Studio 2015 in C++ with a rather complex structure and many source files.

The solution uses some header files from an outside application, that are organized in one folder containing **268 subfolders**, containing other folders and/or header files.

An illustration of the header files folder structure:

[image: An illustration of the header files folder structure]

In other words the outside application has a tree structure of header files to be used when developing custom code for it.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I know that in order to use a header file like `#include <hfile.h>` I need to specify its location in *Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories*. **The problem is that subfolders of this entry are not scanned and I have 268 subfolders and a big project where I cannot edit all includes.**

I think there should be a better way to reference all header files used in the project.
Can someone help me in this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: I would use `#include "Subfolder/hfile.h"` and put the folder containing the subfolders in the include directories (if it is not already).

Comment: Also you don't want to put 268 additional items in your Include directories. Your build times will suffer with low CPU usage spending a large amount of time checking the contents of the directories. I know this from experience with projects like ITK and VTK that in some circumstances can add hundreds of items to your include paths. This can be slow even on a RAM disk under windows (well at least the last time I checked/ I have refactored my CMake scripts to avoid the situation).

Comment: Why do you have so many copies? Do you want these to be included? Do the files have the same names? Maybe you want to use version control software like git?

Comment: The copies that are visible on the screenshot are for illustrating how it looks. This is not the original folder.
I do not really need to add 268 items and build with all of them but since the project has not been written by me I do not know which headers have been used. I will have to manually change all of the includes in the whole project if I use your ```#include "Subfolder/hfile.h"``` suggestion. I wanted to spare myself this job.
Also the project needs to be just be built once and will not be worked on, so git is not going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio cannot be configured to look recursively into subdirectories of directories on the include path ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339971/560648)).

That way *absolute madness* would lie as the potential for conflicts would skyrocket, and the time to resolve includes would also go up.

I'm sorry that you have so many subfolders, but the solution is to fix that. That's an insane project layout. Getting rid of all those "copies" would be a good start…

Comment: I have edited the OP to be clearer that the screenshot is just an illustrative example and not the original folder. I cannot paste the original folder here. I would change the project layout but how would you suggest I do that? The only way I can think of is to edit manually all the includes in the source to use the syntax ```#include "Subfolder/hfile.h"``` as suggested by @drescherjm. I cannot change the folder structure of the outside application.

Comment: This is, ultimately, a social problem, rather than a technical one. You need to have a serious conversation with the project convener.